# How can get data from Node.js inside app.get to react.js?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I'm using sso(Oauth) service that my company has. And I'm trying to get the data from it .

And the process is like this:

when I click the button that has sso Link and client_id or something,
then the backend server get the code (URL query)  and send the code(URL query) to sso and then get the token and userId or something.
and as soon as the token is sent, then website has to change to client side.

And I was trying to get the code(URL query) from node backend server.

however, I can not get the exact url which has the code(URL query),And I want to go back to the client.

So i use `res.direct` in node backend server.

and it's not working and I removed it so that I can know if i can get the data in client,

But the url is changed so I can't get the exact url in client server from backend.

So my question is that how should i get the exact url query from node to react?
and How can I redirect page to client side from backend ??

this is my code :

## Client:

```js
var client_id =
    "clientId ??????????????";

  var state_val = "RANDOM_STATE";
  var redirectURI = "http://localhost:5000";
  let api_url =
    "https://www.ssoservice/oauth2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" +
    client_id +
    "&redirect_uri=" +
    redirectURI +
    "&state=" +
    state_val;

 useEffect(() => {
    const apiCall = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000`);
      console.log(response);
      setRedirectURL(response);
    };
    apiCall();
  }, []);
  // this is the code that i want to get the url query 
  
  return (
            <a href={api_url}>
              <button>
                <FormatListBulletedIcon />
                <p>SSO Login</p>
              </button>
            </a>
  
  )
  
  //go to sso service to get code
```

## backend

```js
app.get("/", cors(), (req, res) => {
 // this url is what i want to get to client side 
 
 
  res.redirect("http://localhost:3000");  // this is not working 
  if (req.query.code !== null && req.query.code !== undefined) {
    var token_url = "https://www.ssoservice/oauth2.0/token";
    var options = {
      url: token_url,
      method: "POST",
      form: {
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        client_id: client_id,
        client_secret: client_secret,
        redirect_uri: redirectURI,
        code: req.query.code,
        state: req.query.state,
      },
    };


    request(options, function (error1, response1, body1) {
      if (!error1 && response1.statusCode == 200) {
        var tdata = JSON.parse(body1);
        var options2 = {
          url: "https://www.ssoservicer/oauth2.0/resource",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + tdata.access_token,
          },
        };
        request(options2, function (error2, response2, body2) {
          if (!error2 && response2.statusCode == 200) {
            var rdata = JSON.parse(body2);
            res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/json;charset=utf-8" });
            res.end(body2);

            console.log(rdata);
             //this is what i want to get 
          } else {
            res.status(response2.statusCode).end();
            console.log("error2 = " + response2.statusCode);
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.status(response1.statusCode).end();
        console.log("error1 = " + response1.statusCode);
      }
    });
  }
});
```